# Implications for developing iOS app on real device only?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, architecture, ios-simulator

I would like to use some lib file (.a) in my app.
I got the files from a 3rd party, to use an IP camera they developed.

As i understand there is no way to open this files, so i will use them as is.

The problem is the files requires real device architecture, so i can't run (or build) them 
on the iOS Simulator.

What will be the Implications for developing iOS app on real device only ?
(Besides a slower build and run time and discomfort..)

Also, is there a way to change this requirement so it could run on the simulator ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own mock library, that exposes the exact same API the vendor provides, and test against that in your simulator.  The functionality your mock library provides can be as boring or as exciting as you desire.

Comment: In order tho that, i need the source code for the library, am i right ?